# Minishell 'segmentation fault, core dumped' error in C

Tags: c, shell, coredump

Following is a part of my code for my shell. The code works, but when I try to enter a command like "ls", my program crashes. I think that's a right error because I try to access to the "/bin" file.

```c
void lecture (char cmd1[], char *argv[]){ 
    int x = 0;
    char ligne [1024];
    char *aux [100], *pch;
    while (1){
        int mot = fgetc (stdin);
        ligne[x] = (char) mot;
        x++;
        if (mot == (int)'\n') break;
    }    
    aux[0] = strtok (ligne, " \n");
    strcpy(cmd1,aux[0]); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1024; i++){
        argv[i+1] = aux[i];
    }
}

int main(){
    char cmd1 [100];
    char cmd2 [100];
    int a = 10;
    char *argv [20];
    char *envp[] = {(char *) "PATH=/bin", 0};
    while (1){
        affichage();
        lecture (cmd2, argv); 
        printf("Test");
        if ( fork() != 0){
            printf("Err");
            wait (NULL);
        }else{
            strcpy(cmd1, "/bin/");
            strcat(cmd1, cmd2);
            execve(cmd1, argv, envp);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You said it crashes but also that "that's a right error", i.e. you think it is correct to crash. So is that a typo, and you think it is _wrong_ to crash? Also, you have code missing; SO expects a full, minimised, reproducible example.

Comment: Anyway, you're making a totally unfounded assumption about the length of `argv[]`s and thus causing a buffer overrun. Please think about what you do when only declaring `20` pointers but then trying to assign to `1025` (because your loop uses `<=`) of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get something working without SIGSEGV with following modification in `lecture`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
```

Example:

```
 ./ms
ls
����: cannot access 'ls': No such file or directory
TestErr
...
```

But you can also debug this as I did with compiling in debug mode:

```
gcc -o ms -g -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -std=c11 ms.c
```

and using `gdb` to check where SIGSEGV occurs.

Note that you are expected to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with full code (here we are missing `affichage`) and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Comment: That shouldn't work either. It just happened to for you. It has undefined behaviour on the final iteration because `argv` is declared as having 20 elements, i.e. indices from 0 to 19, but this code still tries to loop from 1 until 20.

Comment: So my SIGSEGV was due to my loop for

Comment: Yes but as mentionned by @underscore_d the right indices to  use are  0 to 19 (and not 1 to 20): I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers